Question over decomposition of $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$
If $m<n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(m,n)=1$, then there is a natural isomorphism $h: \mathbb{Z}_{mn}\to \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$. But I'm a little confused about what happens when multiplying $m$ on elements. On one hand, if $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$, then $h^{-1}(a,b)=a+bm$. Since $m(a,b)=(0,bm)$, we should have $h^{-1}(m(a,b))=h^{-1}(0,bm)$. However, direct computation gives $h^{-1}(m(a,b))=mh^{-1}(a,b)=m(a+bm)\neq bm^2=h^{-1}(0,bm)$.
There must be something I messed up in the above inequality. Can anyone please let me know where and how? Thanks in advance.

I'm not sure why you say that $h^{-1}(a,b)=a+bm$. What is your conviction as to how $h$ is defined?

@GerryMyerson Thanks for the comment. It seems, the subgroup generated by $m$ is ${0, m,\cdots, (n-1)m}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and the quotient is $\mathbb{Z}_m={0,1,\cdots, m-1}$. So if $a\in \mathbb{Z}_m$ and $b\in \mathbb{Z}_n$, then $(a,b)$ seems to correspond to $a+bm$. Is this wrong?

@OrangeMushroom Isn't it???

$(a,b)\to bxm+ayn \pmod {mn}$ would be the inverse of the natural map from $\Bbb Z_{mn}$ to $\Bbb Z_m×\Bbb Z_n$ when $(m,n)=1,$ where $x,y$ are Bezout coefficients for $m,n$ (that is $xm+yn=1$).
There's numerous sources for a discussion,  including Wikipedia.
